# Google API multiple Services in one call

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

Suppose I want to list a certain Google User Calendars.

I use the **Calendar API** and authorize via OAuth2.0

Now suppose I want to grab the user's mail, for which I need the **Google Plus** API.

How can I do that with **one** single App and one single OAuth2.0 user login?

Comment: Ask for multiple scopes in your OAuth request.

Comment: @SLaks thank you, I did that, but it did not work.

Comment: Why not? What happened?

Comment: @SLaks The whole page blocks (blank page, not even a thrown PHP error or notice) when I try to create a new Google Plus Service object apart of the Google Calendar Service object. I managed to grab the user mail because it is the id of the main calendar and I can list all calendars :). But I was just curious about what was going on. Do you have any reference where I can see that this is the right approach (to call different services scopes from any App)? Why would Google separate the Apps in different types then, instead of making a universal App that uses the scopes it needs?